# update node with npm : not compatible with my operating system

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am trying to update node on my Windows 10 operating system thanks to that command in node.js command prompt:

> npm install -g n

but it gives me this error:

> C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g n npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm
>   ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "-g" "n" npm ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4 npm ERR! code
>   EBADPLATFORM
>
> npm ERR! notsup Unsupported npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your
>   operating system or architecture: n@2.1.8 npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:
>   !win32 npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:
>   win32 npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log

Do you know what happens?

Comment: `npm install -g n npm` with this command, you're updating npm, not the node itself. You can't update node via npm, you'll have to install a different version via the installer or the [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: Simple way to update on windows is download binary file from nodejs.org and install by double clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're having issues with several version of node, you might want to try NVM (Node Version Manager). There is a special version that supports Windows:  https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows